# Scala some_case_class paramet is not a member of Option[some_case_class]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-class

I'm trying to rewrite this script https://www.kaggle.com/paulantoine/light-gbm-benchmark-0-3692/code to Scala, and need to take info from two Case Classes and put it into one. Donor classes are:

```
case class Prods1(product_name: String, aisle_id: Int, department_id: Int)
case class Prods2(orders: Int, reorders: Int)
```

after join they look like this:

```
(Int, (Prods1, Option[Prods2]))
```

then I need to convert them to:

```
case class Product(product_id: Int, product_name: String, aisle_id: Int, department_id: Int, orders: Option[Int], reorders: Option[Int])
```

it is done by following function:

```
def parse_products(product_data: (Int, (Prods1Data, Option[Prods2Data]))) = {
    val product_id = product_data._1
    val product_name = product_data._2._1.product_name
    val aisle_id = product_data._2._1.aisle_id
    val department_id = product_data._2._1.department_id
    var orders = None
    var reorders = None
    if(product_data._2._2.isDefined){
        val p2 = product_data._2._2
        orders = p2.orders
        reorders = p2.reorders
    }
    Product(product_id, product_name, aisle_id, department_id, orders, reorders)
}
```

I get following errors:

```
error: value orders is not a member of Option[Prods2]
   orders = p2.orders
               ^
error: value reorders is not a member of Option[Prods2]
   reorders = p2.reorders
                 ^
```

I tried another option also:

```
def parse_products(product_data: (Int, (Prods1, Option[Prods2]))) = {
    val product_id = product_data._1
    val product_name = product_data._2._1.product_name
    val aisle_id = product_data._2._1.aisle_id
    val department_id = product_data._2._1.department_id
    product_data._2._2 match {
        case Some(p2) => {
            val orders = p2.orders
            val reorders = p2.reorders
        }
        case None => {
            val orders = None
            val reorders = None
        }
    }
    Product(product_id, product_name, aisle_id, department_id, orders, reorders, reorder_ratio)
}
```

That way I get another errors:

```
error: not found: value orders
   Product(product_id, product_name, aisle_id, department_id, orders, reorders)
                                                              ^
error: not found: value reorders
   Product(product_id, product_name, aisle_id, department_id, orders, reorders)
                                                                      ^
```

If you find it possible please correct both options, as I'm doing that to learn and both constructions would be really useful for me, thank you in advance.

Comment: 1st one: you need `val p2 = product_data._2._2.get()`, both 1st and 2nd one -- move `orders` and `reorders` in outer scope (with some default value, like `None`), so they visible in last stmt.

Comment: `error: Prods2 does not take parameters
val p2 = product_data._2._2.get()
                                                  ^`

Comment: When I removed () after get, like this:
`val p2 = product_data._2._2.get`
I got:
`error: type mismatch;
found   : p2.orders.type (with underlying type Int)
 required: None.type
      orders = p2.orders`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a tuple from the `match` and assign to two separate variables, it makes the code shorter and look a bit cleaner.

```
def parse_products(product_data: (Int, (Prods1, Option[Prods2]))): Product = {
    val product_id = product_data._1
    val product_name = product_data._2._1.product_name
    val aisle_id = product_data._2._1.aisle_id
    val department_id = product_data._2._1.department_id
    val (orders, reorders) = product_data._2._2 match {
        case Some(p2) => (Some(p2.orders), Some(p2.reorders))
        case None => (None, None)
    }
    Product(product_id, product_name, aisle_id, department_id, orders, reorders)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it like this, comment about "get" was useful, but there were some more corrections needed:

```
def parse_products(product_data: (Int, (Prod1, Option[Prod2]))) = {
    val product_id = product_data._1
    val product_name = product_data._2._1.product_name
    val aisle_id = product_data._2._1.aisle_id
    val department_id = product_data._2._1.department_id
    var orders: Option[Int] = None
    var reorders: Option[Int] = None
    if(product_data._2._2.isDefined){
        val p2 = product_data._2._2.get
        orders = Some(p2.orders)
        reorders = Some(p2.reorders)
    }
    Product(product_id, product_name, aisle_id, department_id, orders, reorders)
}
```